# Set Upload's filename in Google Analytics API

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

Google Analytics API allows to upload files to custom data sets, [like described here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData). All is working fine, but in the Analytics panel, files uploaded this way get blank filenames. Is there any way to set the name in the API and/or PHP SDK? The doc doesn't seem to mention it, but what is intriguing is the [examples section](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/uploads/uploadData#examples). JavaScript example sets `title` field for some reason, but it's in the body, so I'm not sure how to set it through the SDK.

Here's how my uploads look like, you can see the empty Filename column:

[image]